# Romans 12:1, what is the accurate translation of (λογικὴν)?

Tags: word-study, romans, new-testament

Romans 12:1, what is the accurate translation of (λογικὴν)?:

- Spiritual.
- Reasonable.
- Logical.
- Intelligent.

Romans 12:1 (GNT):

> 1. Παρακαλῶ οὖν ὑμᾶς, ἀδελφοί, διὰ τῶν οἰκτιρμῶν τοῦ Θεοῦ, παραστῆσαι τὰ σώματα ὑμῶν θυσίαν ζῶσαν, ἁγίαν, εὐάρεστον τῷ Θεῷ, τὴν **λογικὴν** λατρείαν ὑμῶν,

Romans 12:1 (DRB):

> I BESEECH you therefore, brethren, by the mercy of God, that you present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, pleasing unto God, your **reasonable** service.

And what is the meaning of:

- Reasonable service or reasonable worship?
- Logical service or logical worship?

Is reasonable or logical worship a mode of worship, or it means the true worship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adjective λογικός (logikos) only occurs in Rom 12:1 and 1 Peter 2:2 and is a notoriously difficult word to translate because there is nothing in English close to its meaning.  The word is very common amongst the Greek philosophers for obvious reasons.

BDAG offers the following meaning "**pertaining to being carefully thought through, *thoughtful***".  However, it is capable of numerous subtleties and shades of meaning.

In Rom 12:1, it probably means "thoughtful service (in a dedicated spiritual sense)" (BDAG).  In this sense, V2 is anticipated (as well as the rest of Rom 12), to be "transformed by the renewing of your mind".  That is, practise Christianity as one endowed with reason.

In 1 Peter 2:2, it probably means something closely related to the above so we might translate the phrase in which it occurs as, "pure *spiritual* milk" (NIV, ESV, CEV, BSB, etc), or more literally but less clearly, "pure *reasonable* milk" (BLB).

It is clear that Paul and Peter are telling us to be thoughtful, intelligent Christians in contradistinction to the mystic rites of some pagan practices. rights ==> rites (obvious from context).

Comment: This word can be a contrast to the actual physical action of a literal sacrifice. Note in BDB: it is to be borne in mind that λ. means spiritual not only in the sense of πνευματικός, but also in contrast to ‘literal’, w. the mng. ‘metaphorical’

Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur (p. 476)

Comment: I fully agree Perry!  Good comment.

Answer (score 2):

Danker' Concise has the following entry.

> λογιϰός, ή, όν [λόγος]—1. ‘consisting of narration’, story-filled, pert. to the message concerning Jesus Christ 1 Pt 2:2 (frequently interpreted here as ‘spiritual’,
>   in the sense of ‘metaphorical’, but such interpretation, suggesting as it does the obvious, is less likely to have occurred to recipients of the gospel as story, cp. vs.
>   3).—2. ‘characterized by careful thinking’, thoughtful Ro 12:1.

I think Paul was appealing to their sense of what "a reasonable person" would consider appropriate service to God.

Answer (score 1):

λογικός, according to Liddlle-Scott's lexicon, is "belonging to speech" or "belonging to the reason, rational". This is a quality that used to distinguish humans from animals. Animals were considered to be *οἱ αλογικοί* -  without the reason because they could not articulate speech as humans do. 
One such example is in the non-canonical protogospel of James, where animals are mentioned to be αλογικοί.

"Reasonable" or rational, or considerate would be a fitting translation for Rom 12:1.

Answer (score 1):

When you yield to God by his mercy, that is your reasonable service. Anything else would be unreasonable because not prompted by God first. You can not approach a King, you must be summoned. The reasonable thing to do is respond to his offer!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Romans 12:1, what is the accurate translation of (λογικὴν)?:**

Romans 12:1 (GNT):

> Παρακαλῶ οὖν ὑμᾶς, ἀδελφοί, διὰ τῶν οἰκτιρμῶν τοῦ Θεοῦ,
> παραστῆσαι τὰ σώματα ὑμῶν θυσίαν ζῶσαν, ἁγίαν, εὐάρεστον
> τῷ Θεῷ, τὴν λογικὴν λατρείαν ὑμῶν,

Romans 12:1 (DRB):

> I BESEECH you therefore, brethren, by the mercy of God, that you
> present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, pleasing unto God, your
> reasonable service.

OR
I BESEECH you therefore, brethren, by the mercy of God, that you present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, pleasing unto God, **with your power of reason.**

"λογικὴν" (logiken) could also  be translated as "way of thinking" or "power of reason"

Romans 12:1-2  (NASB)

> 12 Therefore I urge you, brethren, by the mercies of God, to present
> your bodies a living and holy sacrifice, [a]acceptable to God, which
> is your spiritual service of worship. 2 And do not be conformed to
> this [c]world, but be transformed by the renewing of your mind, **so
> that you may prove what the will of God is, that which is good and
> acceptable and perfect.**

**The "Power of Reason"**

Many of Jesus’ disciples were simple men and women, fishermen, shepherds, farmworkers and most likely with limited education, however, they did have a  God-given asset at their disposal. All were endowed with reasoning power and thinking abilities. The apostle Paul encouraged his fellow Christians to make full use of their "power of reason", " **so that you may prove [to themselves] what the will of God is, that which is good and  acceptable and perfect [Rom12:2b]**

Going back to Romans 1:18-22 Paul condemns the unrighteous, that is the wise men, the Stoics, and the philosophers of his day for   "suppressing the truth" and ignoring the evidence of the creation around them that there is a God. Paul wrote that although they profess to be wise, they became futile in their speculations,  and their unintelligent heart became darkened, they became fools.

Romans 1:18-22  (NASB)

> 18 For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all
> ungodliness and unrighteousness of men who suppress the truth [a]in
> unrighteousness,19 because that which is known about God is evident
> [b]within them; for God made it evident to them. 20 For since the
> creation of the world His invisible attributes, His eternal power, and
> divine nature, have been clearly seen, being understood through what
> has been made, so that they are without excuse. 21 For even though
> they knew God, they did not [c]honor Him as God or give thanks, but
> they became futile in their speculations, and their foolish heart was
> darkened. 22 Professing to be wise, they became fools,"

**Conclusion.**

Paul is counseling his fellow  Christians with their God-given "power of reason" or "thinking abilities " to discern the philosophies and teachings that are not in harmony with the scriptures as useless. And to make reasonable and sound decisions that is good, acceptable and pleasing to God.

"λογικὴν" (lo-gi- ken) from the Greek word lo-gi-gos , in this context conveys the idea of rendering service or worship in a" logical," "rational" or "intelligent" manner. Or as Dottard wrote in a careful "thoughtful" manner.